# Data back ModalController swift

Tags: ios, swift

Hi in the first viewController i have an array:

```
    var corsi =[Corso]()
```

By using function i go to the second called addcorsoviewController:

```
func addCorso() {
        let addcorso :AddCorsoViewController = AddCorsoViewController()
        self.presentViewController(addcorso, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

now in the second viewController i create a new object called nuovoCorso:

```
var nometext: UITextField?
    var creditiCfutext: UITextField?
    var nomeProftext: UITextField?
    var nuovoCorso:Corso?            

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ...
}
func returnToTable(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        nuovoCorso = Corso(nomeCorso: nometext!.text, cfu: 8, nomeProf: "", esameSuperato: false, votoEsame: 23)
        println(nuovoCorso?.nomeCorso)
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

and the function returnToTable i would append the new object at the array of first viewController but i don't know how to append at the array and return back to the first view.
i don't use storyboard.
can you help me??